# FInd analytical solution using pen and paper

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, analysis

$$y′(t) = y(t) − t, 0 ≤ t ≤ 2$$, and intial conditions $y(0) \in [−2, 2]$.
I am supposed to use pen and paper to find a solution to this problem.
I have derived $y$ to be:

$$y = ce^t + t + 1$$

I recognize that when $$t = 0, y(0) = c + 1$$ But I am not sure how to proceed, and to reach an analytical solution.

Comment: only exponential $t$ in the final solution there is no  exponential  $t^2$

Comment: HINT. $y=1+t$ is a particular solution.

Comment: @Intelligentipauca I see that it is a solution to the problem, but how do I get to that answer. Other than just trial and error?

Comment: As $t$ is a 1st degree polynomial, try with a generic 1st degree polynomial: $y=at+b$. And of course you must add the homogeneous solution $y=Ae^t$.

Comment: See the link given in the answer.

Comment: @Intelligentipauca But y in my question description (edited it once I saw that I had written it wrong) is the combiniation of the particular and homogeneous solution. But there seems to be only a solution where $$c = 0$$. And the starting condition confuses me. I don´t understand whether $$y(0)$$ describes an interval of what y at t=0 is, or if it is a starting point?

Comment: Your solution is correct now. If $y(0)\in[-2,2]$, then $c\in[-3,1]$.

Comment: @Intelligentipauca Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that you've made an error of some kind, but it isn't clear what that is. If you take the derivative of your function $y(t),$ you don't get the same thing as if you subtract $t$ from it.

One nice way to proceed is by the [Method of Undetermined Coefficients](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_of_undetermined_coefficients), since your equation is equivalent to $$-1\cdot y+y'=-t,$$ and since $-1$ is a constant and $t\mapsto-t$ is a polynomial function.